# ajax form being submitted twice on 2nd submit, 3 times on 3rd submit, etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For some reason, my form is being submitted once on the first "submit", and then twice on the 2nd "submit" if you don't refresh the page in between the two.

```
$(document).on('submit', ".post-video-form", function(uploadVideo) {
    uploadVideo.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/dev/new/scripts/upload_video.php',
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == 'success') {
                $(".overlay").fadeOut(200);
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $(".overlay").remove();
                }, 250);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".head").before(overlay_success_html);
                    $(".overlay").fadeIn();
                }, 255);
                $(document).on('click', ".close-overlay", function(){
                    $(".overlay").fadeOut(200);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                      $(".overlay").remove();
                    }, 250);

                });
            }

            if (response == 'failed') {
                $(".upload-error").append('Upload error: File must be a JPG or PNG less than 2.0MB');
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            $(".upload-error").append('Upload error: File must be a JPG or PNG less than 2.0MB');
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would need to see more of your code, but maybe your submit handler is being registered an additional time for every post that is made.

try adding a console log or alert on the line before

```
$(document).on('submit', ".post-video-form", function(uploadVideo) {
```

to make sure that the submit event isn't being registered multiple times. If you are generating javascript server side then this may be the case. Otherwise we would need more information.